# Does Calabash supports iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, calabash, calabash-ios

Does calabash start supporting iOS8 ? if not when can we expect a new calabash-ios version upgrade/release to support iOS8 ?

-Mesh

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `calabash-ios` is supported by `iOS 8`.

I am currently using `iOS 8.4`.

By default is `iPhone 5s simulator`.

#### Update

It is supported by `iOS 9`

But the command `calabash-ios setup` has been broken since Xcode 6. Now is much more difficult to setup and configure your project. [See more](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Tutorial%3A-How-to-add-Calabash-to-Xcode)

Btw, you just need to configure once.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calabash-ios supports iOS 8.

Comment: what is the prerequisite for running calabash on iOS8 ?

Comment: update the calabash gems and server to latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good tutorial how to update the client and server version of Calabash [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/B1-Updating-your-Calabash-iOS-version)

Comment: This is the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using iOS 8.1.2 on a physical device and calabash 2.0 pre6 with no real issues.

As per the docs found on their github page [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios#requirements):

> iOS Devices >= 7.1
>
> iOS Simulators >= 8.0

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it does. If you want to access Calabash-iOS with some real iOS devices, there are useful sites like this available: http://testdroid.com/testdroid/8311/how-to-get-started-with-calabash-ios-example

Comment: This post recommends installing gems with `sudo` which is dangerous.